# Python remover() list index out of range

Tags: python, loop, python-2.7, lista

```
def gera_huffman(simbolosOriginal, probabilidadesOriginal):
# gera_huffman(['a', 'b','c', 'd'], [5, 2, 1, 2])

    simbolos = simbolosOriginal  
    probabilidades = probabilidadesOriginal  

    lista = [] 

    while (len(simbolos) > 2):

        ordem = np.sort(probabilidades)
        ordemIndex = np.argsort(probabilidades)        

        novaProbabilidades = ordem[0]+ordem[1]
        novoSimbolo = simbolos[ordemIndex[1]] + simbolos[ordemIndex[0]]


        print novaProbabilidades , novoSimbolo, simbolosOriginal[ordemIndex[0]],simbolosOriginal[ordemIndex[1]]
        print simbolos
        simbolos.remove(simbolosOriginal[ordemIndex[0]])

        print simbolos
        simbolos.remove(simbolosOriginal[ordemIndex[1]])


        print simbolos


        probabilidades.remove(probabilidadesOriginal[ordemIndex[0]])
        probabilidades.remove(probabilidadesOriginal[ordemIndex[1]])


        probabilidades.append(novaProbabilidades)        
        simbolos.append(novoSimbolo)
        print simbolos


        simbolosOriginal = simbolos
        probabilidadesOriginal = probabilidades


        if(len(simbolos) <= 2):
           lista.append([simbolos, probabilidades])
           lista.sort(reverse = True) 
           return lista
```

> Erro: simbolos.remove(simbolosOriginal[ordemIndex[1]])
>   IndexError: list index out of range

Nos vários `prints` que estou a efectuar na lista `simbolos`, no momento antes do erro estou a obter:

```
simbolosOriginal[ordemIndex[0]]= 'd'
simbolosOriginal[ordemIndex[1]] = 'bc'
```

A lista `simbolos` é `['a', 'bc']`.

Sendo que no `print simbolosOriginal[ordemIndex[1]`] tem o valor `'bc'` e ele está na lista não compreendo porque motivo ele diz que o `index` está `out of range`.

Como posso arrumar isso?

Answer (score 0):

Se eu fosse desenvolver o algoritmo de Huffman em python eu não faria dessa maneira, mas sem entrar nesse mérito, alterei ligeiramente o seu código para evidenciar seu erro. Veja:

```
import numpy as np

def gera_huffman(simbolosOriginal, probabilidadesOriginal):
# gera_huffman(['a', 'b','c', 'd'], [5, 2, 1, 2])

    simbolos = simbolosOriginal  
    probabilidades = probabilidadesOriginal  

    lista = [] 

    while (len(simbolos) > 2):

        ordem = np.sort(probabilidades)
        ordemIndex = np.argsort(probabilidades)        

        novaProbabilidades = ordem[0]+ordem[1]
        novoSimbolo = simbolos[ordemIndex[1]] + simbolos[ordemIndex[0]]

        print ('\nlen atual de simbolos: ',len(simbolos) )

        # print (novaProbabilidades , novoSimbolo, simbolosOriginal[ordemIndex[0]],simbolosOriginal[ordemIndex[1]])

        print ('\nSimbolos antes da remoção: \n', simbolos)
        simbolos.remove(simbolosOriginal[ordemIndex[0]])
        print ('\nsimbolos depois da primeira remoção: \n', simbolos  )

        print ('\nA expressão abaixo:')
        print ('simbolos.remove(simbolosOriginal[ordemIndex[1]])')
        print ('Resulta em:')
        print ('simbolos.remove(simbolosOriginal[',ordemIndex[1],']')

        print ('\nA Proxima linha tenta remover algo que existe? Lembrando que:')
        print ('simbolosOriginal é = ', simbolosOriginal)
        print ('ordemIndex[1] é = ', ordemIndex[1])       



        simbolos.remove(simbolosOriginal[ordemIndex[1]])
        print ('\nSimbolos depois da segunda remoção remoção: \n',simbolos)

        probabilidades.remove(probabilidadesOriginal[ordemIndex[0]])
        probabilidades.remove(probabilidadesOriginal[ordemIndex[1]])

        probabilidades.append(novaProbabilidades)        
        simbolos.append(novoSimbolo)

        print ('\n Simbolos apos o append: \n', simbolos)


        simbolosOriginal = simbolos
        probabilidadesOriginal = probabilidades


        if(len(simbolos) <= 2):
           lista.append([simbolos, probabilidades])
           lista.sort(reverse = True) 
           return lista
```

Tentei explicar o erro no própria codificação, reproduzo o resultado abaixo. [Clique aqui para ver a execução e o resultado do códido.](https://repl.it/HGC6/4)

```
len atual de simbolos:  4

Simbolos antes da remoção: 
 ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

simbolos depois da primeira remoção: 
 ['a', 'b', 'd']

A expressão abaixo:
simbolos.remove(simbolosOriginal[ordemIndex[1]])
Resulta em:
simbolos.remove(simbolosOriginal[ 1 ]

A Proxima linha tenta remover algo que existe? Lembrando que:
simbolosOriginal é =  ['a', 'b', 'd']
ordemIndex[1] é =  1

Simbolos depois da segunda remoção remoção: 
 ['a', 'd']

Simbolos apos o append: 
 ['a', 'd', 'bc']

len atual de simbolos:  3

Simbolos antes da remoção: 
 ['a', 'd', 'bc']

simbolos depois da primeira remoção: 
 ['a', 'bc']

A expressão abaixo:
simbolos.remove(simbolosOriginal[ordemIndex[1]])
Resulta em:
simbolos.remove(simbolosOriginal[ 2 ])

A Proxima linha tenta remover algo que existe? Lembrando que:
simbolosOriginal é =  ['a', 'bc']
ordemIndex[1] é =  2
```

Note que o codigo tenta remover um elemento fazendo referencia na lista simbolosOriginal, utilizando o indice 2, mas nesse tempo a lista é =   ['a', 'bc'], isto é, só tem 2 elementos, como o python inicia os indices de listas em 0 (zero), voce só poderia remover com os indices 0 e 1.

[DEMO](https://repl.it/HGC6/4)